# Glyphicon con Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

Como usar glyphicon con bootstrap 4?

Aca dejo un ejemplo de lo bien que funciona con bootstrap3.x pero ahora que migre al 4 dejo de funcionar, porque y como lo soluciono?

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' , href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>


<a href="#" id="#{item.name}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" )>
 link
 </a>
```

y con el 4 no funciona:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' , href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<a href="#" id="#{item.name}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" )>
 link
 </a>
```

Comment: glyphicon dejo de estar disponible para Bootstrap 4.

Comment: y ahora que se debe hacer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Glyphicon** dejó de estar disponible para Bootstrap4.

Puede usar tanto [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/) como [Github Octicons](https://octicons.github.com/) como una alternativa gratuita para Glyphicons.

En la documentación oficial de [Bootstrap4 Icons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/icons/) colocan algunas opciones para los Iconos y es donde se nota que no esta disponible **glyphicon**

**Bootstrap4** también cambió de *Less* a *Sass*, por lo que puede integrar el Sass (SCSS) de la fuente en su proceso de compilación, para crear un único archivo CSS para sus proyectos.

Dependiendo con el lenguaje con el que estés trabajando podrías compilar los glyphicon en tu proyecto.

Si decides usar [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/) en la mayoría de los iconos bastaría cambiar `glyphicon glyphicon-` por `fa fa-`. Puede verlo en el fragmento de código.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<a href="#" id="#{item.name}" class="fa fa-star" )>
 link
 </a>
```

Parte de la respuesta estuvo orientada por el sitio en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612690/bootstrap-4-glyphicons-migration